# NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE on toFile().listFiles()

Tags: java, file, java-8, findbugs

I am getting " NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE" for the below code. I tried with a few options but still getting the similar problem.
Its giving this on below line

```
parentFolder.toFile().listFiles()
if(files !=null && files.length>0)
```

The full code is given below:

```
        final String dir = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf(PATH_SEPARATOR));
        final String logFile = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(PATH_SEPARATOR) + 1);

        final Path parentFolder = Paths.get(dir);
        final File[] files = parentFolder.toFile().listFiles();


        if (files !=null && files.length>0) {
            final Optional<File> mostRecentFileOrFolder = Stream.of(files)
                    .filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith(logFile))
                    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));

            if (mostRecentFileOrFolder.isPresent()) {
                final File mostRecent = mostRecentFileOrFolder.get();
                log.info("Picked up most recent file from path {}", mostRecent.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }
```

**Update: Full log:**

[INFO] Possible null pointer dereference in com.sourav.TestService.setValidFilePath() due to return value of called method [com.sourav.TestService, com.sourav.TestService] Method invoked at TestService.java:[line 85]Known null at TestService.java:[line 85] NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE
[INFO]

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Updated in the description

Comment: The line 85 is the same line which I've pointed above

Comment: Can you check value of parentFolder.toFile().exists().

Comment: Probably "FindBugs" might be asking you to check the return value of "parentFolder.toFile()" for `null`, before executing `listFiles()` on that.

Comment: OOh. Yes. I've changed that line to "if (parentFolder.toFile().exists()) " and it worked. 
Thanks Sujay. Can you tell me the reason why it worked with this and not the old one.

Answer (score 1):

parentFolder.toFile() will return a File Object. If this file does not exist, then listFiles() will throw error.So you need to check whether the file exist before you go for listFiles.